# How to remove underline in css for anchors pseudo element in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

How to remove `text-decoration: underline` for CSS pseudo element in Internet Explorer?

The `+` icon has no underline in other browsers (like Google Chrome), but in Internet Explorer the `+` icon is underlined. How to remove the underline for Internet Explorer?

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/u5m067xq/4/):**

```css
h3 a { 
  text-decoration:underline;
}
h3 a:before {
  display:inline-block;
  content: '+';
  margin:0;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
 <h3><a href="#">link</a></h3>
```

Comment: Does the `+` needs to be clickable, with same action as the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working as you  expected. Default styling of the `a` tag is `text-decoration: underline`. You will have to set it `none`.

```css
span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h3 a:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '+';
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h3><a href="#"><span>link</span></a></h3>
```